# How to share image at SnapChat from my native iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to share image at SnapChat from my native iOS app. I have tried to search for integration process but not able to find any way so I can integrate logic for sharing image from my app in SnapChat.
Please help. If possible, please share any example?

Answer (score 0):

u tried .. when u click non the share button in our app :
  u can pass image or text or data

**check the code:**

```
 NSArray *objectsToShare = @[your text or image objects..];  


UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypePrint,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                               UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

inside u can chose snapchat or Facebook or WhatsApp... all sharing enabled applications.

Comment: Hello Naveen, I don't want to open activity controller. I want to share image on click of a button that on click it open Snapchat and I can share image.

Comment: Suppose I have a default image icon want to share on Snapchat. When I click on button. There are two options:- 1- If it directly share content (image) without open snapchat app. OR 2- If it open snapchat and user wants to edit some content in share.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it'll work**

```
NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Share URL"];

    NSURL *myurl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
    NSArray *myarray = @[myurl];
    NSLog(@"%@",myarray);
    UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:myarray applicationActivities:nil];
```

**incase using iPod Share by using this condition**

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}else {
    UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
    [popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 0, 0)inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the tutorial below for Snapchat share in iOS Swift..

[Snapchat Creative Kit iOS (Swift) - Image, Video, Sticker Sharing](https://mahmudul-razib.medium.com/snapchat-creative-kit-ios-swift-image-video-sticker-sharing-8ec8ed7e5efd)